# How make dynamic breadcrumbs in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to have a dynamic breadcrumbs based on where I clicked on a category but I get an error that says my variable is undefined: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'homeMenu')`. Yet in my `getHomeCategory` function, the console.log of `homeCategory` displays `Perma'Thèque`. I don't understand how to do it, thanks

Here is the code :

```html
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
        },
        data: () => ({
            homeMenu: "",
            breadcrumbs: [
                {
                    text: 'Accueil',
                    disabled: false,
                    href: '/',
                },
                {
                    text: this.homeMenu,
                    disabled: false,
                    href: "/" + this.homeMenu,
                },
            ],
            
        }),
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                console: () => console,
                homeCategory: 'home/getCategory',    
            })
        },
        methods: {
            getHomeCategory ()  {
                if (this.homeCategory === "Perma'Thèque") {
                    console.log(this.homeCategory)
                    return this.homeMenu = "permatheque"
                } else {
                    return this.homeMenu = "null"
                }
            },

            
        },
        mounted() {
            if (this.plantActive) this.loading = false;
            this.getHomeCategory()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data()` is declared here as an arrow function, so `this` refers to the outer scope, not the Vue component instance, but even as a regular function here, `this.homeMenu` won't yet exist.

It seems that you actually want `breadcrumbs` to be reactive to `homeMenu`, so you should move `breadcrumbs` to a [computed prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties):

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    homeMenu: '',
  }),
  computed: {
    breadcrumbs() {
      return [
        {
          text: 'Accueil',
          disabled: false,
          href: '/',
        },
        {
          text: this.homeMenu,
          disabled: false,
          href: '/' + this.homeMenu,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-reactive-field?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I used Element Plus UI and my mind was blown. Check out my blog and the codes. Element Plus is a free library that is great for Vue JS. They have very nice UI for breadcrumb and can be implemented with v-for loop.
https://medium.com/@samchowdhury/create-a-breadcrumb-with-vue-js-and-element-plus-ui-f3e2fde50a3e